# In Typescript "extends" works, but error when assigning derived to super

Tags: typescript

The following code (at [Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJwMLigKAN7ekOgDN4A7YACjFQHMAuaSgW2UYBcALASwgEpoAXgB80AG4B7bgBMB+Iguipk7eKjLQatAkQC+2fdlCQYAETTcxyaZhPRkAD3bIy0mAhQYsEPDsJiabjAAIxBkIWguXgA6UgpKSgERaFxdPgBuA2wjCTIIdmgJYIArRg80WygIsmQAd2hzVEtrSohE9KA)) gives an error `Type 'DerivedClass' is not assignable to type 'SuperClass'` at the variable `obj`. How is this possible, when `DerivedClass extends SuperClass`? Does this contradict Liskov substitution principle?

```js
class SuperClass
{
    func(arg: (me: this) => void) {
        return arg
    }
}

class DerivedClass extends SuperClass
{
    variable = this.func(() => {});
}

const obj: SuperClass = new DerivedClass();
```

In an attempt to further isolate the 'problem', the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgygVwA4FMoBhVdAKAG8yEaFcoB7CfefAEwVEhngQDdgUAJahk+AFwIAFAFsJCCAAshYAJQIAvAD5+DIWwDcZAL5kyKNBgAihIX3YlLCfAA9mAOzYYcBYqTCU1LT0TCzMHALCovia0nKSSirq2ggUxkam5gzukAgMIABWkj6Ejuix7vgA7gg2wvZsZWBSqgZAA) errors for some reason, unless `protected` is removed in both classes:

```
abstract class SuperClass
{
    protected abstract variable: (me: this) => void;
}

class DerivedClass extends SuperClass
{
    protected variable = (me: this) => {};
}

const obj: SuperClass = new DerivedClass();
```

There are many definitions of the Liskov substitution principle, but commonly it is assumed that objects of a derived type can behave like/pretend to be a super type. I would expect an error inside the definition of `DerivedClass` if something is wrong with the inheritance, not on the last line of code.

Comment: The `this` type is implicitly generic and narrows in subclasses, and in your example the type is *invariant* in `this` because it is used in both a function input and output position. It’s like you’ve written `SuperClass<SuperClass>` and `DerivedClass<DerivedClass>` but because the generic type is invariant, things are not compatible. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer explaining fully; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm trying to write a demonstration that the assignment is unsafe, but I'm having a really hard time understanding what on earth these classes do. At no point does it look like you're actually calling the function of type `(me: this)=>this`, and it `func` is essentially of type `(arg: (me: this)=>this) => ((me: this)=>this)` which is so *weird* that I don't see how to proceed. Could you possibly [edit] to make a simpler [mre] that depends on `this` but isn't passing around such nested stuff? Anywhere you use `this` as a type, you probably should actually use `this` as a value also.

Comment: @jcalz, I removed the return type of `arg`, but more minimal is not possible. The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) is unclear, and I don't understand why this does not violate Liskov: the last line shouldn't give a compile error if we `extend`. Explaining why this is weird would require more details (the `variable` is declared abstract in `SuperClass`, and `func` is used as a helper in the `DerivedClass` to write lambda's in which the type of `me` is inferred, the `arg` is used to select properties of the `DerivedClass`).

Comment: If `F<T> extends G<T>`, that doesn’t imply that `F<F<T>> extends G<G<T>>` unless you know that `F` and `G` are covariant. The `this` type is implicitly generic so when you use it, it’s as if the class is generic. This isn’t a violation of LSP unless generic classes are. I’ll take another look when I get off mobile.

Comment: So, take a look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ3YDw); I wrote my own example that doesn't melt my brain, where the `this` type is in a contravariant position (and thus makes the classes invariant).  The top section avoids `this` types, and instead uses explicitly [F-bounded generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification). It isn't an LSP violation that you can't assign a `BarSelf` to a `FooSelf`, even though `Bar<T> extends Boo<T>`. The `this` example below is essentially the same, except with the `T` being *implicit*.

Comment: (see prev comment). Maybe I can rephrase it like this: once you start using polymorphic `this` in your types, it is quite possible to get *class* hierarchies or *interface* hierarchies that are not *type* hierarchies. You are assuming that `interface X extends Y` or `class X extends Y` means that `X` is a subtype of `Y`, but polymorphic `this` can wreck that. It isn't so much an LSP violation as a difference in meaning of what `extends` does in the face of polymorphic `this`. Does that now fully address it for you? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @jcalz: thank you a lot, you helped by 1) providing an example comparing using "this" vs using generic explicitly, and 2) explaining that `class X extends Y` in fact does not neccesarilarly mean that `X` is a subtype of `Y`. Thank you a lot, this fully answers both questions: your last two comments are the answer to the questions.